# How FTP deploy .NET Core WebApp to Azure Linux App Service plan

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I want do deploy code to **Linux App service plan** over **FTP** but I fail because I am missing a step how to "say to app service to use app `DLL` instead of default one".

Code is copied, I even uploaded test zip file and I can't download it, getting `error 404` so how did Microsoft imagine to deploy code over FTP? I couldn't find any info in their documentation regarding this exact case.

I want to avoid using **docker file**, If this can't be done I'll simply switch to using Windows based App service plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application setting screen of your WebApp mention the startup file name
dotnet

Comment: DUH! Well thank you, I started looking into creating custom docker image for every deployment, totally overengineering the problem :D. It is interesting how this piece of information is not specified anywhere in the documentation!